# Call EJB through a forward proxy

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly, ejb-3.0, wildfly-26

I have a wildfly 26.0.0 server working behind a company proxy and exposing EJBs.

My fat client can connect directly to the server if they are both on the same VLAN but I can't make it works through the company proxy.

The client use undertow and xnio to connect to the server (using the dependecy `org.wildfly:wildfly-ejb-client-bom:26.0.0.Final`).
I tried to use:

- remote+http protocol using legacy file *jboss-ejb-client.properties*
- full http protocol using *wildfly-config.xml* file and
  `org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory` context
  factory.

With both methods, direct connection works but not through proxy.

I set the proxy with VM options: `-Dhttp.proxyHost=<host> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<port>` and also tried with `-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true`.

Note that a `curl` call through the proxy also works, so the required ports are opened.

The issue seems to be [known](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/XNIO-274) but the suggested patch doesn't works.

Is there any way to have a fat client call EJB through a forward proxy?